# django - checking to see if filter returns anything in the queryset

Tags: django, django-errors

I'm a newb to Django.  I need to check to see if a queryset returns any values at all, and if not, to skip to the next item in the loop.  I tried try.. except ObjectDoesNotExist and that's not working.  If a filter doesn't find anything, what does it return?  How do I check for it?

Here's the existing code:

```
def assign_family_riders(leg):
    remaining_leg_riders = list(leg.riders.all())
    for car in CarAssignment.objects.filter(leg=leg):
        driver_family = car.driver.family
        try:
            riders = leg.riders.all().filter(family=driver_family)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            continue
        for rider in riders:
            car.riders.add(rider)
            remaining_leg_riders.remove(rider)
    return remaining_leg_riders
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to specifically check. If the filter doesn't return any objects, an EmptyQuerySet will be returned and the forloop will never be entered.

```
riders = leg.riders.filter(family=driver_family)
for rider in riders:
    ...
```

If you really want to, you could simply do:

```
riders = leg.riders.filter(family=driver_family)
if riders:
    for rider in riders:
        ...
```

The [`ObjectDoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.DoesNotExist) exception is only raised when you are trying to retrieve a particular record using [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get):

```
try:
     rider = leg.riders.get(...)
except Rider.DoesNotExist:
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

As Timmy said in his answer, your loop will not be entered if the queryset returns nothing. On the other hand, if you really want to know the number of records a filter will return, you can call its `count()` method: `CarAssignment.objects.filter(leg=leg).count()`
 This performs a `SELECT COUNT(*)` for you in the background without retrieving any records.

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count) for more information.

Comment: Don't you think that he would have to hit the DB twice, once for count and then if count>0, second time for retrieving the desired records? As far as see, he doesn't require the try... except block at all and follow as Timmy has said.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to do this is to use [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#exists) on the queryset before iterating over it or doing anything else that might perform a more intensive interaction with your database.

An example from the docs;

> The most efficient method of finding whether a model with a unique field (e.g. **primary_key**) is a member of a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet) is:
>
> ```
> entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=123)
> if some_queryset.filter(pk=entry.pk).exists():
>     print("Entry contained in queryset")
> ```
>
> Which will be faster than the following which requires evaluating and iterating through the entire queryset:
>
> ```
> if entry in some_queryset:
>    print("Entry contained in QuerySet")
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure queryset returns nothing. You can probably check it using `./manage.py shell` then see what is in `riders`.